# how can i check uncheck functionality in jquery in checkboxlist?

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox list I need to implement the check uncheck functionality like. When some one click on Όχι(none) all check box will be uncheck.

```
    <TABLE id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages class=ms-authoringcontrols border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top><INPUT style="PADDING-LEFT: 5px" id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_0 CHECKED type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570$ctl00$ddlSpeakForeignLanguages$0></TD>
<TD><LABEL for=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_0>Όχι</LABEL></TD>
<TD vAlign=top><INPUT style="PADDING-LEFT: 5px" id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_4 type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570$ctl00$ddlSpeakForeignLanguages$4></TD>
<TD><LABEL for=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_4>Αλβανικά</LABEL></TD>
<TD vAlign=top><INPUT style="PADDING-LEFT: 5px" id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_7 type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570$ctl00$ddlSpeakForeignLanguages$7></TD>
<TD><LABEL for=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_7>Ισπανικά</LABEL></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top><INPUT style="PADDING-LEFT: 5px" id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_1 type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570$ctl00$ddlSpeakForeignLanguages$1></TD>
<TD><LABEL for=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_1>Αγγλικά</LABEL></TD>
<TD vAlign=top><INPUT style="PADDING-LEFT: 5px" id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_5 type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570$ctl00$ddlSpeakForeignLanguages$5></TD>
<TD><LABEL for=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_5>Ρώσικα</LABEL></TD>
<TD vAlign=top><INPUT style="PADDING-LEFT: 5px" id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_8 type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570$ctl00$ddlSpeakForeignLanguages$8></TD>
<TD><LABEL for=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_8>Ιταλικά</LABEL></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top><INPUT style="PADDING-LEFT: 5px" id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_2 type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570$ctl00$ddlSpeakForeignLanguages$2></TD>
<TD><LABEL for=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_2>Γαλλικά</LABEL></TD>
<TD vAlign=top><INPUT style="PADDING-LEFT: 5px" id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_6 type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570$ctl00$ddlSpeakForeignLanguages$6></TD>
<TD><LABEL for=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_6>Ουκρανικά</LABEL></TD>
<TD vAlign=top><INPUT style="PADDING-LEFT: 5px" id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_9 type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570$ctl00$ddlSpeakForeignLanguages$9></TD>
<TD><LABEL for=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_9>Τούρκικα</LABEL></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top><INPUT style="PADDING-LEFT: 5px" id=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_3 type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570$ctl00$ddlSpeakForeignLanguages$3></TD>
<TD><LABEL for=ctl00_m_g_0a9e1440_6a3d_47b2_9ccb_dd6176913570_ctl00_ddlSpeakForeignLanguages_3>Γερμανικά</LABEL></TD>
<TD vAlign=top></TD>
<TD vAlign=top></TD></TR></TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Oh my, what kind of thing produced this HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
$('table :checkbox:first').change(function() {
  if(this.checked)
    $('table :checkbox:gt(0)').attr('checked', false); 
});
$('table :checkbox').change(function() {
  $('table :checkbox:first')
    .attr('checked', $('table :checkbox:gt(0):checked').length == 0);
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4N7V6/1/), it has the following behavior:

- When you uncheck everything, "none" checks itself
- When you check anything besides "none", it clears the "none" check
- You can't uncheck "none" alone...only checking *another* checkbox will uncheck "none"

This should ensure the correct input and be fairly intuitive, give it a shot see how you like it.

Comment: hehe I was lazy in answering this one because of the codes of the OP.. ;) I better delete my answer... +1